# CSS Grid: how do I use minmax() while naming lines?

Tags: css, css-grid, minmax

I'm trying to understand how to use minmax() while also naming lines in a grid

let's say I create a grid with 12 divs and I divide them in 4 column and 3 rows. I want column and rows to be at least 200px and max 400px or other sizes I specified in minmax. I also want to name my lines.

I tried writing this

```css
.naming-lines {
            display:grid;
            grid-template-columns: [inizio-colonna] minmax(200px, 400px) [colonna-2] minmax(300px, 400px) [colonna-3] minmax(400px, 600px) [fine-colonna];
            grid-template-rows: repeat([row-start], minmax(200px, 400px) [row-end]);
        }

        
.container {background-color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            display:grid;
            max-width: 2000px;
            border-color:red;
            border-style: solid;}

.box {
        background-color: aliceblue; 
        border-style: dashed; 
        border-color: blanchedalmond;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: larger;
}
```

```html
<h1>Naming lines</h1>
<div class="container naming-lines">
        
    <div class="box box1">I'm box 1</div>
    <div class="box box2">I'm box 2</div>
    <div class="box box3">I'm box 3</div>
    <div class="box box4">I'm box 4</div>
    <div class="box box5">I'm box 5.</div>
    <div class="box box6">I'm box 6.</div>
    <div class="box box7">I'm box 7.</div>
    <div class="box box8">I'm box 8.</div>
    <div class="box box9">I'm box 9.</div>
    <div class="box box10">I'm box 10.</div>
    <div class="box box11">I'm box 11.</div>
    <div class="box box12">I'm box 12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it doesn't work. I don't understand how minmax and naming lines work together.

Comment: your template row is invalid, you cannot have such syntax. Follow the same you used for column

Comment: yeah I forgot to start with the number of repeats, it should be repeat(3, [row-start] minmax(200px, 400px) [row-end])  but i guess it's not possible to use minmax and naming lines at this point. I haven't found examples online yet..

Comment: you can use minmax() and names like you did with columns, simply repeat the same logic without using *repeat* (write them individually)